# Passing minion list to Jenkins pipeline, Error: workflowScript: 15: illegal string body character after dollar sign;

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, salt-stack

Below is the Jenkins pipeline. which runs a state against the list of minions stored in a .txt file on the salt master server. The below command runs fine on the salt master cli:

```css
 salt --list `awk -vORS=, '{ print $1 }' /srv/salt/TMjenkins/minions.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'` test.ping
```

However, when I run it through the Jenkins pipeline, I get illegal string body character after dollar sign. The salt master is in a remote server, hence I can't execute the cmd natively.
so, far i have tried with passing the cmd in """ """ and ''' ''', also { print \"${1}\" }. Nothing has worked so far. Any suggestion, appreciated.

```css
pipeline = {
      ansiColor('xterm') {
      def remote = [:]
      remote.name = 'saltmaster'
      remote.host = 'xx.xxx.xx.x'
      remote.allowAnyHosts = true
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'saltmaster', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'ops')]) {
            remote.user = 'xxx'
            remote.password = password 
                
            stage('Filetransfer') {
                  
                 sshCommand remote: remote, command: " salt -L  `awk -vORS=, '{ print \"${1}\" }' /srv/salt/TMjenkins/minions.txt | sed 's/,$/\n/'` test.ping "
                      
            }
        }   
    sh '/home/jenkins/jenkins-data/slack_notification.sh " ${minionid}" "Deployment finished successfully" "good" ":jenkins:"'
      } 
 } 
postFailure = {
    sh '/home/jenkins/jenkins-data/slack_notification.sh " ${minionid}" "Unfortunately deployment was unsuccessful this time" "danger" ":jenkinserror:"'
}

postAlways = {
    echo 'Cleaning Workspace now'
    env.WORKSPACE = pwd()
    sh "rm ${env.WORKSPACE}/* -fr"
}

node{
     properties([
     parameters([
         
   string(name: 'Region', defaultValue: '', description: 'Region for which the process should run. ')
             ])
      ]) 
    try {
        pipeline()
    } catch (e) {
        postFailure()
        throw e
    } finally {
        postAlways()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your `$` sign if you want to pass it over. So:

```
awk -vORS=, '{ print $1 }' /srv/salt/TMjenkins/minions.txt
```

becomes

```
sh "awk -vORS=, '{ print \$1 }' /srv/salt/TMjenkins/minions.txt "
```

and

```
sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

becomes

```
sh "sed 's/,\$/\n/'"
```

Finally, instead of using bash scripts to send Slack notifications, you should use [Slack plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack/), like this:

```
slackSend color: "danger", text: "Failed"
```

[See also](https://github.com/jenkinsci/slack-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, Martac. In the current pipeline, the notification goes out as a success or failed based on the return of all the minions for the cmd test.ping. How can i send the notification separately for each minion based on its result?  Note: I want to pass all the minions from the .txt file and not of it own from the cmd.

Comment: That should be a separate question.